# Configurar color y densidad de contornos de polígonos en mapa con geopandas y matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, mapa

Estoy armando un mapa de calor para ver establecimientos sin internación en Argentina en base a datos espaciales, utilizando GeoPandas y Matplolib. El mapa está todo ok, pero no estoy logrando poder delimitar -por ejemplo con líneas negras- los polígonos de las provincias.

```
import pandas as pd    
import geopandas as gpd
import descartes
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable


## Importación establecimientos sin internación
path_establecimientos = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oblitterator/codigos_y_fuinciones/main/est_sin_internacion.csv'
establecimientos_sin_int = path_establecimientos, encoding = 'UTF-8')
establecimientos_sin_int['%_sin_int'] =  round(establecimientos_sin_int['total']/sum(establecimientos_sin_int['total'])*100,2)
establecimientos_sin_int.head()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
## Carga de mapas
path_prov = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oblitterator/codigos_y_fuinciones/main/argentina.geojson'
map_arg = gpd.read_file(path_prov, encoding = 'UTF-8', index_col = [0]).rename({'NAME_1':'Provincia'}, axis = 1)
map_arg = pd.merge(map_arg, establecimientos_sin_int[['%_sin_int', 'Provincia']], on ='Provincia')

# Control del tamaño de la figura del mapa
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (20,25))

# Control del título y los ejes
ax.set_title('Proporción de Establecimientos sin Internación por Provincia (Elaboración Propia en base a REFES- 2022)', 
             pad = 20, 
             fontdict={'fontsize':20, 'color': '#4873ab'})
ax.set_xlabel('Longitud')
ax.set_ylabel('Latitud')

divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)

cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="4%", pad='1%')

# Mostrar el mapa finalizado
map_arg.plot(column='%_sin_int', cmap='Greens', ax=ax, zorder=2, legend=True, cax = cax, legend_kwds={'label': "Proporción por Provincia",
                       'orientation': "vertical"})
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En pocas palabras, lo que me gustaría es que se visualizaran más los contornos. Gracias!!

Comment: Buen día, y ¿Qué has intentado? O ¿En qué parte del código te devuelve error?

Comment: Buenas! No, no es que tengo error. Sino que no he encontrado la sintaxis para realizarlo! Por defecto las líneas aparecen en blanco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el parámetro que buscas es `edgecolor`. No tengo tus datos por lo que no puedo replicar tu gráfica, pero sí puedo hacer una mini-demo:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
path_prov = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oblitterator/codigos_y_fuinciones/main/argentina.geojson'
map_arg = gpd.read_file(path_prov, encoding = 'UTF-8', index_col = [0]).rename({'NAME_1':'Provincia'}, axis = 1)
map_arg.plot(edgecolor="black")
```

lo que produce la figura

[image: Mapa]

Y por si te lo preguntas, se puede cambiar el grosor de las fronteras con el parámetro `linewidth` (el valor por defecto es 1.0)

Comment: Muchas  gracias!!